# Can't access variable declared by SpriteBuilder

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

I'm doing this [tutorial](https://www.makegameswith.us/tutorials/getting-started-with-spritebuilder/levels/).

To separate menu button and game content I added a `CCNode` named `_contentNode` that include all gaming content and publish it to `XCode` as the tutorial indicated.

But I get `Use of undeclared identifier '_contentNode'` error when I try to run it in XCode.

This is the SpriteBuilder screenshot how I set the variable. Is there something wrong with this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I forgot I must declare variable in the code like this:

```
@implementation Gameplay {
    //...
    CCNode *_contentNode;
}
```